# How do you ensure that decision tree does not have irrelevant attributes?

Tags: decision-tree

I have a data set containing variables that predict if a person needs additional learning material. If I were to structure the data set so that certain color of dress almost always correlated with "Yes" (needs material), what are some approaches to tackle this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Have a look at [Information Gain](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shapiro/EE596/notes/InfoGain.pdf).

Comment: I'm just looking for some approaches one can take. I'd take a manual look at the data; in this case its obvious why color of dress does not matter but I'm unsure if there are other approaches.